# Xcode commit issue with git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, project, commit

I'm having an issue with Xcode trying to commit some changes to a Git repo. Today, I created a branch from master in order to work on future updates of an app while keeping the ability to fix the release version.
The problem I have occurs when committing changes. I get the following error message:
`error: pathspec 'Furtivus.xcodeproj' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

The thing is, back in the early days of the project, I changed the name of the bundle and the project and it is no longer called "Furtivus". I've tried looking into the `.git` `directory` where my local repository is located. I've also tried looking for any files containing "Furtivus" on my mac with no results. I can't find where to change this name.
Obviously Git is trying to find the old project that was renamed, so how do I change that?

I've done a lot of searching, in the documentation regarding Git, and on Stackoverflow and nothing seems to cover how to handle Git and a project name change.